# Chart.js: How to change the x-Axes background color?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I'm using "chart.js": "3.0.0" and  "react-chartjs-2": "^3.0.3" and I'm trying to chage the x-axes background color.
I could change the color of font but  can not change the background
[image]

I tried to use

```
 backgroundColor: 'red'
```

but not working..

```
  const options = {
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          font: {
            size: 10,
          },
          backgroundColor: 'red', // not working
          color: 'black',　　// worked
        },
      },
      y: {
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 2,
        },
      },
    },
  };
```

Does anybody know how to change it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom inline plugin for this:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: 'red'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        backgroundColor: 'blue'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      scaleBackgroundColor: {
        color: 'yellow'
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [{
    id: 'scaleBackgroundColor',
    beforeDraw: (chart, args, opts) => {
      const {
        ctx,
        canvas,
        chartArea: {
          left,
          bottom,
          width,
        }
      } = chart;

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(left, bottom, width, (canvas.height - bottom));
      ctx.fillStyle = opts.color || 'white'
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }]
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.4.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Edit:**
You can also use the `backgroundColor` option in the axis settings:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: 'red'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        backgroundColor: 'blue'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        backgroundColor: 'yellow'
      }
    }
  },
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.4.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```